# How to run maven web application through cmd

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web-applications

I am a newbie in making web application development and I'm trying to make a website that plays video using embedded Tomcat and maven. I have only one static jsp file and I can run the program on intellij on localhost but I am finding extreme difficulties to run this project in cmd with the command line (mvn exec). My main goal is to run this program on a server I rented and then using the domain name I registered to access the website. Here is my pom.xml file

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 

 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>maven.movie.com</groupId>

 <artifactId>movieweb</artifactId>

 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <packaging>war</packaging>

 <name>movieweb Maven Webapp</name>
 <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
 <tomcat.version>8.5.23</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
  <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
  <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
  <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
  <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

movieweb

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.0</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.1</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
        <programs>
          <program>
            <mainClass>launch.Main</mainClass>
            <name>webapp</name>
          </program>
        </programs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>assemble</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>launch.Main</mainClass>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>launch.Main</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <port>9090</port>
      <path>/</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then you can run the maven task provided by this new plugin like this

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it does not work :( The error is showing  A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]

Answer (score 0):

@piy26 
 
Thanks for the solution. 
But it is useful when we want to test the application on local where web server is not installed.

@Karan, for local you can use above solution.
But for running the code on the server, I will suggest to run ***mvn clean package*** command and as described in your pom.xml it will build a war and this you can keep in web server directory and start the web server.
This has to be done on the server you rented. I will suggest go with AWS free tier for now.
I know this a long process and to avoid this you can use Spring Boot where no need to deploy war files web server is embeded.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I guess I'll stick to using Tomcat since I have finished doing it, as I'm only left with deployment and would not want to use other frameworks for a small project.